# RSpec attribute hash

Tags: ruby, rspec

Can someone explain to me what is wrong here. Learning RSpec - I am receiving a failed test with message - expected: "Miller" got: nil. I thought that the second 'before block' would simply merge the middle_name with the original @valid_attributes. What is the correct way to do this. I know that I can simply say p.middle_name to assign it but I am trying to learn the concepts of RSpec.

```
describe Person do
  describe "Validations" do
    subject { p }
    before { @valid_attributes={first_name: "Joe", last_name: "Sample"} }

    ...

    context "with optional middle name" do
      let(:p) { Person.new(@valid_attributes) }
      before { @valid_attributes.merge({middle_name: "Miller"}) }

      its(:middle_name) { should eq("Miller") }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your problem: `Hash#merge` returns a new hash, you want `Hash#update`.
2. How to do it better? This is not just an advice for testing, but for programming in general: if you update and reuse variables you're gonna hit some problems with state; take a more functional approach. In this particular case you should use [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) or similar gem to easily create objects without having a `@valid_attributes` being updated who knows where.

Comment: Agreed.  It seems you are not just new to RSpec, but to Ruby as well.  You need to become aware of which methods mutate an object and which do not.  As tokland pointed out above, #merge does not mutate, while #update does.

Comment: It's true, I am learning Ruby as well. Thank you for the advice.